# Finding the maximum height of left and right subtree

Tags: binary-tree

I would like to implement the following function:

```
    def get_height(root, d):
        
        if root.left:
            left = get_height(root.left, d + 1)
        if root.right:
            right = get_height(root.right, d + 1)
```

The idea is simple: For a given node, I want the maximum height of its left and right subtree. The code is not finished yet obviously. I am looking for a clean way to finish the code above, so the return value is the max. height of the left and right subtree.

Comment: `return max(left, right) + 1`, no need for `d`. You need a base case also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just *complete* the method, you need to add a `return` and ensure that the base case works. The base case is when the node is a leaf. So you need to give default values for `left` and `right`:

```py
def get_height(root, d):
    left = d
    right = d
    if root.left:
        left = get_height(root.left, d + 1)
    if root.right:
        right = get_height(root.right, d + 1)
    return max(left, right)
```

This is however not the best practice. You should avoid the extra `d` parameter. You can do without, and let each call return the height of *that* node, without having to know anything about the parent. When the recursive call is made, the *caller* can add 1 to the *returned* value:

```py
def get_height(root):
    left = 0
    right = 0
    if root.left:
        left = get_height(root.left) + 1
    if root.right:
        right = get_height(root.right) + 1
    return max(left, right)
```

You can also move the base case one step further, so only one `if` is needed:

```py
def get_height(root):
    if not root:
        return -1
    return max(get_height(root.left), get_height(root.right)) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers, that really helped a lot! Could you please explain how the last solution works? Or more so why it works. I cannot really understand what each recursive function is returning in that particular case.

Comment: A recursive call returns the height of the node passed as argument. So for instance `get_height(root.left)` could return 1 if `root.left` has only leaves as children. And if `root.right` is a leaf node, then `get_height(root.right)` should return 0. Assuming that works, then it is clear that `max(....) + 1` is the correct answer for the current node. The base case here is when the argument is `None`. In that case it is an empty tree (nothing). The height of nothing is -1 (because a node with no children has height 0 -- those "children" thus have a height of -1).

Comment: puh that is hard to grasp initially. But this works rather bottom up than top down doesn't ti ? Because the last nodes with children start with a height of 1, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is bottom up. Every recursive call only cares about their own business and returns the height as if their argument is the root. It is up to the caller to adjust that height to represent its own argument's height.

Comment: one last question, does the max function starts "running" as soon as it has 2 arguments from the recursive calls? For example, what if 1 value is returned and we have something like ```max(-1, get_height(root.right))```?

Comment: Yes, that's right. First the recursive call(s) must come back with results, and then `max` is calculated from that. One or two of those values could be -1.

Comment: I was practicing a bit and tried to find the depth of an nested list, i.e. ```a = [1, [[[2]]]]``` should return 3. I was trying to take a very similar approach to yours with the main functionality being ```return 1 + get_depth(a[1:])```. But I could not find out how to use the max function here?

Comment: I think I figured it out ```return 1 + max(get_depth(a[0]), get_depth(a[1:]))```